# Splitting string arrays with delimiter

Tags: arrays, split, arduino, arduino-c++

I'm using the following code to split a char array:

```
    char* Split(char* e, int index) {
  index = index -1;
  char* v[index +2];
  char *p;
  int i = 0;
  p = strtok(e, ",");
  while(p && i < index +2)
   {
    v[i] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    i++;
  };
//  Serial.println(v[0]);
  //Serial.println(v[1]);
 // Serial.println(v[2]);
  return v[index];
 };
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
 char array[]="1,3,4,55,6,7,66";
 Serial.println("array:");
Serial.println(array);
 char *out;
 out = Split(array,2);
 Serial.println("out:");
 Serial.println(out);
 Serial.println("array:");
 Serial.println(array);
 out = Split(array,2);
 Serial.println("out:");
 Serial.println(out);
```

The first time I call the function, everythin is fine. The result I get is "3" , and that is what I expect.

But with the second call of the function, things goes crazy, and I get just some hieroglyphics.

When I check the variables with the Serial output, I can see that "array" is the second time just "1", and this might be the reason of the curious output of the function.

But I don't understand how the first call of the function can affect the value of "array", because this variable is not touched in the function.
Can anybody help me with clarifying this issue?

The output of the serial interface is lke this:

```
array:
1,3,4,55,6,7,66
out:
3
array:
1
out:
⸮}⸮a⸮⸮-:⸮⸮⸮m⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮]⸮ʻ⸮T⸮;⸮⸮⸮N}⸮⸮⸮⸮{R⸮U)⸮⸮⸮[G⸮⸮`j⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮v⸮⸮wz⸮⸮s⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮}⸮⸮2⸮⸮vz~⸮⸮⸮⸮O}⸮⸮⸮/⸮⸮nv⸮⸮^j⸮yO⸮7{⸮⸮⸮⸮z⸮Z⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮7[⸮⸮⸮j⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮w)⸮⸮c⸮⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮v⸮⸮׺⸮m/V⸮ys<⸮⸮ٿ⸮⸮⸮׆⸮+>ֻ⸮z6⸮=⸮D⸮⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮e⸮⸮?⸮=⸮⸮W⸮⸮⸮⸮}⸮e⸮ߣN绮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮Y⸮⸮޴f⸮v⸮⸮u⸮p?⸮⸮^h⸮⸮}⸮⸮ݼ⸮^Wo⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮;s⸮⸮⸮⸮wZ⸮⸮⸮~⸮7⸮⸮⸮r⸮⸮⸮⸮)⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮f⸮⸮O⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮
⸮⸮7⸮⸮a.⸮⸮.kG⸮⸮8⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮U⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮'⸮we⸮⸮⸮M⸮{⸮⸮Lu⸮no⸮⸮⸮>⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮y⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮,'>}⸮⸮⸮+⸮X⸮⸮⸮/⸮⸮ױ⸮⸮⸮⸮̲⸮⸮-_M⸮⸮⸮⸮L~⸮#Φz~⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮{/⸮_⸮:⸮jmc⸮m]S⸮_3⸮>o⸮׷⸮ݸv⸮⸮⸮|⸮
⸮⸮{_^⸮⸮o⸮?⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮^⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ퟺ⸮⸮߿⸮⸮p⸮⸮⸮w?=⸮⸮⸮X⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮_⸮oy⸮⸮M⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮[⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮޿7wE~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮N⸮⸮o⸮x⸮=v/⸮⸮⸮⸮>⸮9⸮⸮ί⸮Y_Q⸮⸮l⸮⸮}'⸮⸮}⸮?⸮⸮ޭ⸮6⸮7⸮{⸮T⸮⸮⸮ ⸮r⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮
ܽ+'⸮⸮⸮⸮G⸮f⸮z⸮Gn⸮⸮n⸮/⸮⸮⸮⸮/⸮⸮⸮⸮Q⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮o⸮;⸮L⸮⸮r⸮⸮⸮⸮n/߿ſ⸮⸮⸮⸮q⸮⸮⸮ݮ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮+⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ﷹln?⸮⸮⸮⸮q⸮⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮q⸮-⸮⸮{(⸮⸮f⸮⸮{⸮v⸮܀⸮oq⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮߽⸮⸮nj⸮⸮⸮os⸮6۟g⸮⸮⸮⸮"⸮⸮7Z7⸮⸮yo⸮ӟ⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮Vr⸮⸮]_⸮׷SS⸮_⸮w⸮⸮⸮wl⸮⸮⸮⸮P⸮⸮z⸮⸮m{⸮⸮⸮ݛs⸮(⸮⸮r⸮⸮˷:⸮%⸮⸮⸮⸮Z⸮⸮⸮m⸮W⸮⸮⸮⸮ם*⸮⸮⸮[>⸮⸮⸮/⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮⸮|⸮.⸮⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮ꍥ⸮⸮⸮|⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮7~Ls⸮!⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮{⸮x⸮g⸮⸮|֍om~~⸮⸮⸮{⸮cϠ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮>;⸮W⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮q⸮⸮[:⸮'⸮#⸮o⸮⸮_⸮uϾ⸮⸮⸮⸮[⸮⸮^⸮⸮⸮n⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮>/⸮_⸮⸮-⸮⸮⸮⸮s⸮⸮⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮/⸮[w⸮⸮r⸮⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮,⸮⸮ݯ⸮⸮⸮7ÿ⸮:⸮⸮⸮⸮Ί⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮t[|⸮⸮w⸮F⸮⸮⸮
```

Comment: index = index -1;
  char* v[index +2];  Das ist fantastisch!:)

Comment: The function strtok changes the source array. So after the first call the array contains the string "1".

Comment: OK, strange! And how can I avoid this behaviour? I have eight substrings which I want to separate with this function.

Comment: I have countered  only seven substrings that represent numbers.:) You need to rewrite the function. For example the function could return either a position or a pointer to the target substring plus the length of the substring using strcspn and strspn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has anybody a better idea?

The solution depend on your data, if your data is always like a string with list of integers separated with `,`, then it will probably better to split it into an `int` array, you can then write a generic `split()` function.

```
#define NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT 7

int splitted[NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT];
const char* delimiter = ",";

void split(const char *str, const char *delimiter) {
  char temp[strlen(str)+1] = {0};
  memcpy(temp, str, strlen(str));

  int i=0;
  char *p = strtok(temp, delimiter);
  while(p != NULL) {
    splitted[i++] = atoi(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  }
}

int setup() {
  char array[]="1,3,4,55,6,7,66";
  
  Serial.begin(115200);

  split(array, delimiter);

  // get every splitted element as an int
  for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT, i++) {
    Serial.print("Out:");
    Serial.println(splitted[i]);
  }

  //if you really want to have string as result
  Serial.println(String(splitted[3]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it by making the array independent from change by strtok:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  char array[]="1,3,4,55,6,7,66";

 char *out;
 char array2[8];
 strcpy(array2,array);
  Serial.println("array2:");
Serial.println(array2);
 out = Split(array2,2);
 Serial.println("out:");
 Serial.println(out);
 Serial.println("array3:");
  char array3[8];
 strcpy(array3,array);
 Serial.println(array3);
 out = Split(array3,2);
 Serial.println("out:");
 Serial.println(out);
}
```

Not that elegant, but it works!!

Has anybody a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,great!
Yes my data is always int. So your function is perfect for me.
But for the sake of a clear structure, I would prefer to work with a return value, instead of changing the global variable "splitted".
Is that a good practice? Or do you prefer your variant for saving RAM?

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, rather than an answer. Sure, you can return a point to an array as you like. I'm just showing the light...

Comment: To avoid the global variable, you could change the function prototype to `split(const char *str, int *splitted, const char *delimiter)` by passing in the pointer of `splitted`, this allows the `splitted` to be declared at where it use than as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here my final solution for this task. The function just returns a single value, according to the given index:

```
int splitStrToInt(char *str, int index) {
    //******************
    //This function splits a string that is separated by commas and converts the values ​​to int,
    //according to the given index
    //caution!! The string may only consist of numerical values ​​!!
    //Example: "1,3,4,55,6,7,66"
    //******************
    index--;
    char e[strlen(str) + 1] = { 0 }; 
    memcpy(e, str, strlen(str));
    int v[index + 2];
    char *p;
    int i = 0;
    p = strtok(e, ",");
    while (p && i < index + 2) {
        v[i] = atoi(p);            
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
    ;

    return v[index];
}
```